# Connect to WebHDFS using powershell: How to set the Different Credentials

Tags: powershell, webhdfs

I am rtying to connect te WebHDFS by powershell and have been retrieving some errors. I think the 401 error is because of the Credentials.

The code I've been using is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Put -inFile c:\Users\petter\Documents\example.txt -Uri "https://drona-haproxy.corp.com:2000/gateway/drona/webhdfs/v1/user/petter/example.txt?op=CREATE"
```

How could I set different parameters in the Credentials under "Invoke-RestMethod"?

THe error that I've been retrieving is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -inFile c:\Users\petter\Documents\load ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Credential` parameter with `Invoke-RestMethod`.

I would have thought you'd need to remove `-UseDefaultCredentials` but [the `Invoke-RestMethod` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1) says they're part of the same parameter set - not sure how that works.

related: [WebHDFS Authentication](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#Authentication)